# What are you ideal vim configuration for php development?

Tags: php, vim, editor

I use VIM editor for PHP, i know many people will point to PDT but somehow I  like to stay with VIM and so

What are your suggestions for ideal VIM configuration for PHP Development ?

Comment: Thought this question is more of an community wiki nature, so updated it to be an community wiki.

Comment: vim is an excellent editor, but it takes time to find a configuration that suites your own style. Its like a pair of shoes, once they are broken in and comfortable it will be your favourite. For now I suggest you just start with the basic configuration which has php syntax highlighting. Meanwhile start to learn about make files, development in VIM is largely based around a Makefile, i.e. you write code, use the command :make, address any errors, test your program, rinse and repeat. In the case of PHP I imagine your make file is just going to be a command that reloads a webpage in firefox.

Comment: +1 for shoe example, really liked it.

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki is an excellent site for several tips on how to configure Vim. For example: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PHP_editing

Comment: Also Andrei Zmievski's "VIM for (PHP) Programmers" - http://zmievski.org/2007/02/vim-for-php-programmers-slides-and-resources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably want to use a PHP syntax file such as: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1571

FWIW: Personally I am enjoying learning vim at the moment but still prefer netbeans for PHP development because it has many features that I need, such as automatic scp to a remote server and remote debugging with XDebug.

Comment: @Justin: Just curious, can we do remote debugging using eclipse editor. Currently I debug using `var_dumps` and `echo`.

Comment: Yes; from what I understand it is possible, but I have personally only used Netbeans for PHP debugging. But I have been *very* happy using Eclipse for Python debugging so I would definitely look into it. In either case, you would need XDebug installed on the PHP server.

Comment: I had no clude about Xdebug, thanks for the tip! (and a good question) :)

Comment: Eclipse also has a plugin for talking to ZendDebugger http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/, in case you're using ZendServer.

Answer (score 3):

If you've used PDT and like it, you might want to look into [Eclim](http://eclim.org/). It allows you to use vim, but hooks into eclipse for projects, code completion, etc. This makes it a little easier to jump into PDT for debugging, then back to vim for coding.

Answer (score 3):

you really should be using Tobias Schlitt's VIP, which is "VIM integration for PHP, including the phpDocumentor for VIM (PDV) script. The main component is a VIM file type plugin, which configures a lot of VIM enhancements for more comfortable PHP editing in VIM.".

I've been using it since before its name changed from PDV to VIP and it really is superb.

You can get it off github at http://github.com/tobyS/vip

Answer (score 0):

It really varies depending on your style, but a good place to start is to create a file called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/php.vim`. If you find any useful mappings for PHP, put them into this file (use the `<buffer>` option for mappings to stop them leaking into other types of files). Once you know what sort of values you like for `tabstop`, `autoindent`, `smartindent` etc, put them into the ftplugin file using `:setlocal`.

Answer (score 0):

I like this, to automatically fold your code for you..

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623

Folding in Vim in general...

```
:h folding
```

and to get into the php spirit, use the phpx colorscheme.. : )

```
http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/colors/phpx.vim
```

Check out that project in general, for some nice colorschemes.

Answer (score 0):

What abou config files and usage tips? [Vim for PHP programmers](http://www.slideshare.net/ZendCon/vim-for-php-programmers-presentation)